# Mysql Trigger IF target field changed

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, triggers, conditional-statements

I would like to fire an UPDATE trigger only if a certain fields has been modified.
Is it possible to do with a if statement; execute a particular query.

Exemple (Not working as shown):

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `catch_mytable_update`//
CREATE TRIGGER `catch_mytable_update` AFTER UPDATE ON `mytable`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

IF (old.name != new.name) THEN

DELETE FROM trigger WHERE tablename='mytable' AND rowid = new.id;
INSERT INTO trigger (tablename, rowid, cmd, cmduser, time) VALUES('mytable', new.id, 'UPDATE', CURRENT_USER(), NOW());

ENDIF//

END//
```

Delimiter: //

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing:

```
    IF (name.old != name.new) THEN
```

to:

```
    IF old.name != new.name THEN
```

Comment: Sorry, yes are right. This was a spelling mistake when I typed the question. I tried the change, and I am still getting an error :(

Comment: We'll need to know the MySQL error code or message for us to help :)

Comment: Here is the following error I get when I run the query mentioned:
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 9

Comment: Also, what is the table that's named 'trigger' actually used for?

Comment: The table trigger is used for monitoring triggers occurring in several tables.
This query already works fine with no IF statement. thx

Comment: Try changing: ENDIF// to: END IF; http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/if-statement.html

Comment: Mark, thank you very much for your help! I guess the delimiters got me mixed up...

Comment: That's great. Glad to of helped.